# AngularJS $scope.$watch firing in all instances of my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller called SearchDatatablesContactsCtrl defined as follows:

```
function SearchDatatablesContactsCtrl($scope, $state, $stateParams, ...) {
    $scope.controllerName = "SearchDatatablesContactsCtrl";
    var vm = this;
    vm.instanceName = "SearchDatatablesContactsCtrl_" + new Date().getTime();
    vm.nameValues = {};

    if ($stateParams.nameValues !== null && $stateParams.nameValues.personId != "") {
        vm.nameValues.personId = $stateParams.nameValues.personId;
        vm.nameValues.kindOfSearch = $stateParams.nameValues.kindOfSearch;
    } 


    $scope.$watch(function(){
        return vm.nameValues;
    }, function(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log("watch executed for " + vm.instanceName);
        //http request to fill datatable
    });

    ...
```

My view has tree tabs with 1 table each using SearchDatatablesContactsCtrl injected through $stateProvider.state. The problem comes when I search for a value using the text field which ng-model is attached to nameValues,
it runs 3 http requests to get the values for the datatables (one per instance).

The result of the execution is:

```
watch executed for SearchDatatablesContactsCtrl_1462436421603
watch executed for SearchDatatablesContactsCtrl_1462436421703
watch executed for SearchDatatablesContactsCtrl_1462436422023
```

Is there any way to force an instance of a controller to watch only the changes in its scope?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Interesting problem. I couldn't reproduce it in a simple plunker though, so I can only guess a solution. What happens if you verify in the watcher's callback that `newValue !== oldValue` and only then proceed with the http request?

Comment: Just tried that and same result:

    `watch executed for SearchDatatablesContactsCtrl_1462455648997
    watch executed for SearchDatatablesContactsCtrl_1462455649078
    watch executed for SearchDatatablesContactsCtrl_1462455649439`

Comment: Could you add a Plunker with the implementation of the tabs please?

Comment: The Problem was that I had several tabs with one SearchDatatableContactsCtrl so all of the instances were fired. The solutions was to provide a TAB_ID for each tab and check inside the $watch if the watch being fired belongs to the correct tab. Thanks everybody for your help